# how to access ejb 1.1 from spring 3

Tags: java, spring, ejb, spring-3

There is a legacy application that uses ejb1.1 and runs on websphere 6. I would like to develop a simple web application with spring 3 which can access these ejb. I have gone through the spring documentation but don't find any way as they assume access to the bean (session bean source code). How to invoke the remote ejb (without having access to the source code)

PS: i have gone through similar questions and dont find answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have an easier time connecting Spring MVC to a hamster wheel. But since you don't have access to the source code, I think you need to simply wrap your legacy application with REST or some other messaging apparatus. Without more details on how the legacy application actually works, I can't get more specific.